# SQL syntax confusion (Natural Join)

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

Here is the following code

```
postgres=# SELECT title,name,borrower.address WHERE library_branch NATURAL JOIN
book NATURAL JOIN book_loans NATURAL JOIN borrow WHERE library_branch.branchname
='Sharpstown' AND dateOut='12/10/2014';
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "NATURAL"
LINE 1: ... title,name,borrower.address WHERE library_branch NATURAL JO...
                                                         ^
postgres=#
```

Not sure why it's giving the error. I thought I did the natural join correctly. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it postgressql or mysql? Please use the right tag

Comment: the prompt seems to be the psql command line client not MySQL. Tables you are selecting from need to use a `FROM` clause not a `WHERE` clause (that is true for Postgres and MySQL). See the manual for details: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM

Comment: --> **WHERE** <-- library_branch NATURAL JOIN?

Comment: Sorry about that im using pgadmin3 and thank you also a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: NATURAL JOIN is a bit dangerous. Applications may quit working after adding a column to a table. (Similar to the "SELECT *" problem.)

Answer (score 0):

You have a `where` keyword where the `from` should go:

```
SELECT       title, name, borrower.address 
FROM         library_branch -- There's a WHERE here in the OP
NATURAL JOIN book 
NATURAL JOIN book_loans 
NATURAL JOIN borrow 
WHERE        library_branch.branchname = 'Sharpstown' AND 
             dateOut = '12/10/2014';
```